# Lua - make bytecode

Tags: lua

So, I've been asked to make a bytecode for the simpliest code:

```
print("Hello, world!")
```

But I have no idea how and I can't seem to find any information on how to make one... Can someone please help? I use Lua for Windows as a compiler. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it from Lua without `luac` using `string.dump`. Try for instance

```
f=assert(io.open("luac.out","wb"))
assert(f:write(string.dump(assert(loadfile("foo.lua")))))
assert(f:close())
```

If the code to be compiled is in a string, use `load(s)`.

You can also save the file below as `luac.lua`and run it from the command line:

```
-- bare-bones luac in Lua
-- usage: lua luac.lua file.lua

assert(arg[1]~=nil and arg[2]==nil,"usage: lua luac.lua file.lua")
f=assert(io.open("luac.out","wb"))
assert(f:write(string.dump(assert(loadfile(arg[1])))))
assert(f:close())
```

Comment: Yes, but you can change the name in the script of course. Or adapt it to receive the name of the output file as `arg[2]`. You'll have to change the first `assert`
.

Comment: Thanks man, this helped me out the most. So, am I just giving them the luac.out file?

Comment: Yes, but you can name it `bar.lua` instead if you want, because Lua will load precompiled byte code transparently.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Lua compiler](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaCompilerInLua) (see [`luac`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/luac.html) manual):

```
# the default output is "luac.out"
echo 'print("Hello, world!")' | luac -

# you can execute this bytecode with the Lua interpreter
lua luac.out
# -> Hello, world!
```

Comment: Where can I download luac?

Comment: It's officially provided with [Lua source code](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/). See also the [installing section](http://www.lua.org/start.html) that contains Windows instructions (e.g LuaDist).